# How to read lines in batches from a text file in Node.js

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I am trying to figure out a way to open a Node.js Stream to read a text/CSV file as a Stream, so that:

- Read a batch of lines
- Pause the reading
- Do some async processing: Parse all lines to an array of objects, then send them to an API.
- Resume reading
- Go to step 1

I have been using [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) with some success, but it doesn't quite work because [pause() doesn't stop it right away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25793453/node-js-readline-interface-pause-event-does-not-pause-input-stream), and it keeps reading more lines while the previous batch is still processing. The end result is the downstream API call chokes on concurrent batches, and I get throttled.

I would like to "close the faucet" while a batch is processed, so I can backoff if I get throttled, backoff, then retry until the batch is fully processed, THEN I can resume reading.

There is an old package [event-stream](https://github.com/dominictarr/event-stream) based on [split](https://github.com/dominictarr/split) that handle the line splitting, but both projects are archived.

Is this something that can be solved with a [Transform Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform)

Answer (score 1):

The previous solution actually lead to some duplicated processing. The quickest way I found to solve this would be the following, still using csv-parse:

```js
import parse from 'csv-parse';
import fs from 'fs';

const stream = fs.createReadStream('FILE_PATH').pipe(parse());

let recordsInBatch = [];
let recordsCounter = 0;
const BATCH_SIZE = 1000;

for await (const record of stream) {
  recordsInBatch.push(record);
  recordsCounter += 1;
  if (recordsCounter >= BATCH_SIZE) {
    await yourAsyncCall(recordsInBatch);
    recordsCounter = 0;
    recordsInBatch = [];
  }
}

await yourAsyncCall(recordsInBatch);
```

Answer (score 0):

example with csv

`npm i csv-parser --save`

```
const csv = require('csv-parser')
const fs = require('fs')

let counter = 0;
let batch = []

const stream = fs.createReadStream('FILE_PATH')
.pipe(csv())
.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('data', data)

    batch.push(data)
    counter ++

    if(counter > 5000) {
        stream.pause()

        setTimeout(() => {
            // YOUR ASYNC PROCESSING
            counter = 0;
            batch = []
            stream.resume()
        }, 5000)
    }
})
.on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e)
})
.on('end', () => {
    console.log('end');

   // YOUR ASYNC PROCESSING
});
```

example with txt

`npm i line-by-line --save`

```
const LineByLineReader = require('line-by-line')

let counter = 0;
let batch = []

rl = new LineByLineReader('FILE_PATH');

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    console.log('line', line)

    batch.push(line)
    counter ++

    if(counter > 5000) {
        rl.pause()

        setTimeout(() => {
            // YOUR ASYNC PROCESSING
            counter = 0;
            batch = []
            rl.resume()
        }, 5000)
    }
})
.on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e)
})
.on('end', () => {
    console.log()

    // YOUR ASYNC PROCESSING
})
```